# Permission to use Firebase Cloud Storage has been refused. This operation could not be completed. When fetching a downloadURL, use firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-security

I have such a code that publishes a picture to my online storage buckets properly.

I'd want to retrieve the picture's URL using another function so that I may display it on my page.

```
"error": {
"code": 403,
"message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

buddy this works great for me

```
service firebase.storage {
   match /b/{bucket}/o {
   match /images/{imageId} {
   // Only allow uploads of any image file that's less than 5MB
   allow write: if request.resource.size < 5 * 1024 * 1024
           && request.resource.contentType.matches('image/.*');
    }
   }
 }
```